# LINQ2Entities and Oracle: comparing on a String/nclob

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ora-00932

I have an Entity called Product in Entity Framework which has a name field, which is of type String.
This gets transformed to a NCLOB column in Oracle, by the Oracle Software I installed for Visual Studio. 
I am able to insert a few Products.

Now I want to do for example a LINQ-query where I select a single Entity based on its name:

```
Product p1 = ctx.ProductSet.Single(p => p.Name == "FIETS");
```

This results in an exception which tells me that error ORA-00932 (inconsistent datatypes).
What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should harass Oracle about it. This should work.
As long as it doesn't, their Entity Provider is broken.

Apart from this showing how broken their EDM support is:
Is it really required to have a name field of type nclob? Wouldn't a nvarchar be sufficient?